# How to manage what to display in a gridview from a dropdown list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

First time posting here.

I have a specific problem with a simple webapplication, where i got stuck on having a gridview bind to a dropdownlist and displaying the contents of the selected item in the ddl.

I can bind the gridview to the ddl fine, and it will display the information that is contained within all of the items of the ddl.  But i cant for the life of me figure out how to **only** display the selected objects information in the gridview.

And ive also been unable to re-fire the databind from the ddl's onSelectedItemChanged.

```
    protected void ddlPersons_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "message";
        this.GridView1.DataSource = Persons;
        this.GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

(Persons is the a list of objects which i have confirmed to contain the information that i require. the label is simply there to see if the method fires. which it also does but the databind will not.)

I have tried many different answers from stackoverflow but none seems to work on my project and im completely lost as to what i should do.

**Updated**
heres my page load. in the method loadList() i fill the Persons list. its contents will not change.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        loadList();
        }
    }
```

As for using ddlPersons.SelectedItem to filter which contents, i have no idea how that is done. I mean i have tried using different ways to access the selected object, but still unsuccessful.

**Update 2**

The markup of the gridview and dropdownlist

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Nr">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.getSetFirstName") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Namn">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.getSetFirstName") %>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.getSetLastName") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Ålder">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.getSetAge") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPersons" runat="server" OnSelectedItemChanged="ddlPersons_SelectedItemChanged" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPersons_SelectedItemChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Hi your dropdownlist have property AutoPostBack True?

Comment: @user2969391 can you show the Grid view and the dropdown list design view.

Comment: @user2969391 The `DataSource` have any data? I mean where you are filling the `Persons` list

Comment: Yes the dropdownlist have autopostback True. The Persons list is static and i fill it at pageload.

Comment: do you have the postback in your page_load?

Comment: Again, please show the code where `Persons` is populated, not where you call a function that populates it.  Also show where `Persons` is declared.

Comment: Remove your `OnSelectedItemChanged` event .

Answer (score 2):

Since you are manually binding the GridView, you need to use `ddlPersons.SelectedValue` to filter the contents of the `Persons` collection.

As for why your GridView isn't populating, it's not a problem with the code you have posted.  You might want to include your GridView and DropDownList markup and whatever code you're using to populate `Persons`.

**Edit:**

Assuming you want to filter `Persons` on one of its properties called category, you can filter a `List<Person>` for instance, using LINQ with a function like this:

```
private List<Person> FilterPersonsByCategory(List<Person> liPersons, string strCategory)
{
    return liPersons.Where(p => p.Category = strCategory);
}
```

Then you could use the function like this:

```
GridView1.DataSource = FilterPersonsByCategory(Persons, ddlCategory.SelectedValue);
```

Having said all that, this is assuming your collection `Persons` is a `List<T>`, and also keep in mind that the above solution will load the entire result set from the database and filter the list in the web server's memory.  If your data retrieval function returns `IQueryable<T>`, the function above can be modified slightly to make the DB query more efficient.  Let me know if you're interested in that.

**Edit #2**

I can't find the reference documentation offhand, but if memory serves `GridView.DataSource` requires an object that implements `IEnumerable` interface so the `DataBind()` process can get an enumerator object to iterate over the data.  Based on your comment it looks like this is part of the problem.

Comment: Is there any chance you could elaborate on how to use ddlPersons.SelectedValue to filter? I caught a bug with my pageload and that solved my problem with getting the gridview to re-populate.

Comment: Not sure if you are using LINQ; If not, just iterate over the collection in your function and check for the value of the property you want to filter on, then build a list to be output.

Comment: I found a solution to what i wanted to do after i read up on the things you suggested. Since this is a rather simple webapplication all i needed to do was to supply the datasource with a new list instead of the actual object. I am so very thankful for the time and effort you (and others) put into this. TYVM

Comment: @psudocoder Please note that begging for upvotes/reputation is generally frowned upon by the community. Though not addressing accepts, here is an [reference Post on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/begging-for-votes/)

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 This is hardly begging for an upvote.  I asked the OP to close out the question since he left his gratitude in the form of a comment and is a brand new user.  Note that leaving comments that belong in meta is also frowned upon.

Comment: @pseudocoder Since he is a new user he can't vote up right now anyway, so why don't give him a link to the [about] page or similar, explaining that accepting an answer helps future visitors to find the correct one, instead of asking `... please upvote and/or mark the answer as correct.`

Comment: +1 from my side because you gave a nice answer and put effort into it.

Comment: @pseudocoder I didn't want to sound offensive, but simply asking new users to upvote/accept an answer doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 Since this is a behavior I think is appropriate and don't wish to change, I've started a meta QA on it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204713/is-it-ever-appropriate-to-ask-new-users-to-mark-your-answer-as-correct-or-ask-fo

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
          loadList();
          BindGrid();
        }
    }

Public void BindGrid()
   { 
   // Code to Bind Gridview.
   }
```

See since you have kept your `Person` as static and it's value never changes,  and you have provided your gridview datasource as `Person` in `ddlPersons_SelectedItemChanged` event .So your gridview content do  not changes .

**2** . To filter out values You can do one thing on `RowDataBound` event you can hide all other rows accept one which is related to your dropdown.SelectedValue .

Or create different methods to populate your gridview .

```
 protected void ddlPersons_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Label1.Text = "message";
        //this.GridView1.DataSource = Persons;
       // this.GridView1.DataBind();
       int ddlVal = Convert.toint32(ddlPersons.SelectedValue);
       BindGridUsingDdl(ddlVal); 
    }

 Public void BindGridUsingDdl(int ddlVal)
   {
      //Your code to populate gridview 
       // Gridview.Datasource = filter your list according 
      // to selected value of dropdown.
   }
```

Comment: I understand how that could work aswell. Im afraid i found a simple solution to my problem. I simply didnt understand that i had to provide the datasource with a list instead of the actual object that i wanted to bind the gridview with. I am taking the examples provided here to learn more about efficient ways to solve this problem. Thank you very much for your time and effort!

Comment: 1) What makes you think `Persons` is static?  2) Why filter data in the gridview when you have access to the underlying data source?

Comment: @pseudocoder It's an option to filter data in gridview however i do not prefer that, but as i said create separate method to populate gridview using ddl in which i suggested to make your query to fetch data from DB using filters.